# Springframework constructor-arg

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, constructor-injection

I have a MainClass which have 2 variables.  I would like to pass those 2 values to a springframework bean class "Test".  how do I define that in applicationContext.xml and also how do I pass those 2 variable values to the bean "Test".

Ex:

```
class MainClass {
       public int var1;
      public int var2;
      public Test test;

   public void setVar1(int var11) {
    var1 = var11;
   }

    public void setVar2(int var22) {
        var2 = var22;
    }

   public static void main(String args[]) {

       ApplicationContext context = 
           new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
      Test = context.getBean("test");
   }
  }
```

------------ TEST class ------------

```
public class Test {

 public Test (int var1, int var2) {}
}
```

------------- applicationContext.xml -------------

```
   <bean id="test" class="com.path.test">
       <constructor-arg index="0" type="int" value="????"/>
       <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="????"/>
   </bean>
```

Comment: It's a bit of a weird thing to do, but you could make use of PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer. Something like this: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?71815-Passing-Bean-properties-using-java.util.Properties

Answer (score 7):

You can pass values in like this:

```
<bean id="test" class="com.path.test.Test">
   <constructor-arg index="0" type="int" value="123"/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="456"/>
</bean>
```

You should remember to put your fully-qualified class name as the value of the `class` attribute.

That said, your `Test` class is not holding onto its state.  If you want to get a hold of the values you specified in your `applicationContext.xml`, you should create some members of `Test`:

```
public class Test {
    private int v1;
    private int v2;

    public Test (int var1, int var2) {v1 = var1; v2 = var2;}

    public int getVOne() {
        return v1;
    }

    public int getVTwo() {
        return v2;
    }
}
```

You should then be able to access these in your `main` method like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    ApplicationContext context = 
       new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    Test test = context.getBean("test");
    int v1 = test.getVOne();
    int v2 = test.getVTwo();

    System.out.println("V1: " + v1 + " V2: " + v2); //output: V1: 123 V2: 456
}
```

Comment: var1 and var2 values should be passed from Main class. Those are not constant values. Can I configure that in applicationContext.xml file?

Comment: That is not what you use Spring for.  Dependency injection is about setting your dependencies up outside of code.  What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: "Main" class defines 2 variables. "Test" class is instantiated from "Main" class and should pass those 2 variables to "Test" class. How can I acheive this using Spring.

For Ex:
      Main Class:
         int var1 = getValueFromDatabase(1);
         int var2 = getValueFromDatabase(2);
         Test test = new Test(var1, var2);

Comment: I understand your example, but Spring is not necessary to create an instance of `Test` in this case.  Here, you should create `Test` using the `new` operator just as you have shown: `Test test = new Test(var1, var2);`

Answer (score 0):

As Nicholas says, it's a bit of a weird thing to do, but you could achieve it using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Something like this:

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("var1", Integer.toString(var1));
        properties.setProperty("var2", Integer.toString(var2));
        configurer.setProperties(properties);

        FileSystemXmlApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext();
        context.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(configurer);

        context.setConfigLocation("applicationContext.xml");
        context.refresh();
        Test test = (Test) context.getBean("test");
 }
```

*NOTE: var1 and var2 should be static if you want to reference them from main()*

Then reference the placeholders like so:

```
<bean id="test" class="com.path.test">
   <constructor-arg index="0" type="int" value="${var1}"/>
   <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="${var2}"/>
</bean>
```

See also this forum thread: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?71815-Passing-Bean-properties-using-java.util.Properties

API doc: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

HTH

Comment: I am also using "PropertyPlaceHolders" in my applicationContext.xml file, which retrieves values from "multiple properties" files. When I used your approach, it is not taking the properites from applicationContext.xml file.  Please help.

Comment: Well, I think PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is only meant to be used once per ApplicationContex. So, maybe try another approach!

Comment: e.g. call if you're getting the values from the DB, the datasource should be set up in the applicationContext xml, and then you can use a MethodInvokingFactoryBean to invoke getValueFromDatabase(1) ... http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html